# What is different between `request.data['param-name'] ` or `request.data.get('param-name')` in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I tried to get data from API

1  `request.data['param-name']`

output -:'9121009000'

2  `request.data.get('param-name')`

output -:'9121009000'

Both are giving the same result.

So Which one is the best to use get data and Why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 6):

If you perform a `request.data['key']` call, behind the curtains, Python will call the `__getitem__` function of `request.data`. We can read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__) and see:

> **`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`**
>
> Returns the value for the given `key`. If the `key` has more than one
>   value, it returns the last value. **Raises
>   `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError` if the key does
>   not exist**. (This is a subclass of Python's standard `KeyError`, so
>   you can stick to catching `KeyError`.)

Whereas if you perform a `request.data.get('key'), it will call the`.get(..)` function, and we see in the [documentantation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get):

> **`QueryDict.get(key, default=None)`**
>
> Uses the same logic as `__getitem__()`, with a **hook for returning a
>   default** value if the key doesn't exist.

So it means that if the key does not exists, `.get(..)` will return `None`, in case you did *not* provide a default, or it will return the given default if you query with `request.data.get('key', somedefault)`.

Typically the latter is used in case the value is optional, and you want to reduce the amount of code to check if the key exists.

Answer (score 2):

Yes both of them will give you the same results, but what makes them different is the way they retrieve the data for a given key. For this you need to understand how dictionaries in python works, lets define a dict:

```
>>> kwarg = {'name': 'John'}
>>> kwarg['name']
'John'
>>> kwarg['age']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'age'
>>>
>>> kwarg.get('age', 25)
25
```

In the above example in the first method the key has to be present whereas in second case I can define a default value if the key is not found.